# Terminal freezes

Tags: gnome-terminal

I having a problem with my terminal. The terminal is not taking any keyboard input and just opens and stays in this state.

[image]

Comment: You've not provided any OS/product/release details; but your terminal looks like it was opened with a specific command that produced an error, then ended (*with an option for the terminal to freeze on completion so messages can be read before the terminal is closed*).  You could opt to have the terminal closed (*as is the usual default*), but then error message(s) or completion message(s) aren't seen.

Comment: os - Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS ,os type - 64bit,gnome v - 42.5

Comment: fixed there was a process blocking terminal. thank you